# How to Upgrade to PHP 5.5 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, php5

What is the proper way to upgrade from PHP Version 5.4.32 to PHP Version 5.5.22 on Windows? All that I can find is how to to install.

PHP is already running on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit alongside IIS, just need to move on to a newer version of PHP

Answer (score 8):

This is seems to be covered fairly well in `install.txt` included in the PHP zip downloads.

Quoting from that file ...

> Manual Installation Steps
>
> ...
>        Upgrading from a previous PHP version: Previous editions of the
>        manual suggest moving various ini and DLL files into your SYSTEM
>        (i.e. C:\WINDOWS) folder and while this simplifies the installation
>        procedure it makes upgrading difficult. We advise you remove all of
>        these files (like php.ini and PHP related DLLs from the Windows
>        SYSTEM folder) before moving on with a new PHP installation. Be sure
>        to backup these files as you might break the entire system. The old
>        php.ini might be useful in setting up the new PHP as well. And as
>        you'll soon learn, the preferred method for installing PHP is to
>        keep all PHP related files in one directory and have this directory
>        available to your systems PATH.

With that caveat, should just be a matter of installing new version of PHP in new folder and updating IIS config to use the new path.

Answer (score 2):

The manual installation was not going well for me, but the Microsoft Web Platform Installer worked well for me.  https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using the PHP Manager for IIS is a very easy way to use the newest PHP.
https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/

- download the newst php (http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.0.2-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.zip)
- Extract your PHP-Zip File to a useful directory such as C:/PHP/php-7.0.2
- Install PHP Manager with the installer from codeplex or using Platform Installer of IIS
- Register your new PHP with the recently installed PHP Manager(selecting the fast cgi of the PHP-Path above)

That should work for you!

Kindly,

Maes